# How to keep selected dropdown box value in next page dropdown

Tags: java, html, drop-down-menu

My html page is divided in two and contains sidebar and content, in sidebar I have two dropdown boxes, one for school year and another for student name in respective school year selected in 1st dropdown and next is submit button. When I click on submit button it will redirect to next page and next page also looks same but in content page it shows selected student profile, in side bar the same two dropdowns will be there. The problem I am facing here is, first I will select school year and name. Its fine, when it goes to next page the dropdowns will be at initial stage but I want the selected year and name to be displayed on dropdown box, how can I do this?

Some one suggested me to keep the values selected in session after it goes to next page set the value of the dropdown.

Here is my code for dropdown,

```
<select style='width: 200px;'
            id="combo_zone11" name="alfa1">

            <c:forEach var="grade" items="${gradeInfo}">
                <option id='syear' value="" selected="selected">
                <option value=${grade.getDropDownId()}>${grade.getDropDownName()}</option>
            </c:forEach>


        </select>
```

How can I keep selected value in next page dropdown. please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in many ways.

Since you're working in java, you can set the selected values to a hidden field, and while redirecting to next page you can set the values to request object.

Or if the target browsers support HTML5 localStorage, you can make use of it - on dropdown change, save the selected option to local storage using javascript. in the second pages load event, get the values from local storage  and set the drop downs respectively.

Something like -

```
//Script in page1
window.onload = function(){
   var dd = document.getElementById('combo_zone11');
   dd.addEventListener('change',function(){
     localStorage.setItem('ddValue', this.value)
   });
}

//Script in page2
window.onload = function(){
 var ddValue= localStorage.getItem('ddValue');
 var dd= document.getElementById('combo_zone11');
 for(var i = 0;i < dd.options.length;i++){
        if(dd.options[i].value == ddValue ){
            dd.options[i].selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also make use of cookies, sessionStorage, queryStrings etc each method has it's own advantages and disadvantages...

Comment: I think this looks easy. ., I ll try it now

Comment: @T J I am getting ddValue null in next page

Answer (score 0):

Use `select=selected` by passing the id

like

```
<option value="${GroupLi.partyClassificationTypeId if_exists}" selected="selected"> ${GroupLi.description?if_exists}</option>
```

GroupLi is the list name used to iterate 
as:

```
<#list Group as GroupLi>
```